# socat forwarding to multiple addresses

Tags: linux, socat, multiplexing

I have a single incoming video stream, and I'd like to set up multiple processes to handle it, each running at its own address. After some reading it seems **socat** is one way to do this

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:1934,fork,reuseaddr TCP4:someaddress:1935
```

This forwards everything to the target address, but it lets me bind one target only. Is there a way to bind multiple target addresses with socat? If I try multiple individual binds I get an "address already in use" error on subsequent binds. I'm not forced to use socat, anything that lets me copy my incoming stream is good, if anyone knows a better approach. Thanks.

Comment: I'm scratching my head over this one. It should work. Does `netstat -nl -A inet` show a listener on port 1934?

Comment: ... I mean after the first client connects, and you want to connect again.

Comment: Have a look at https://gist.github.com/mathieue/3505472 taken from a comment into a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057619/using-socat-to-relay-one-tty-stream-to-multiple-tcp-ip-destinations-plus-to-one

Comment: @AndrewSchulman Yes, it shows a listener on that part.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek that gist is for UDP ... how would I do that for TCP?

Comment: Just replace `udp4-listen` by `tcp4-listen` and the two `udp-sento` by `tcp4` ? See answers of this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480967/using-socat-to-multiplex-incoming-tcp-connection

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Tried 

socat - tcp4-listen:1934,fork | tee >(socat - tcp4:127.0.0.1:1935) >(socat - tcp4:127.0.0.1:1936)

I can see something is listening on 1935, but it just consoles out a bunch of garbled characters when I try to stream to it, and nothing after that.

Comment: `socat -u` instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on my earlier comments, I have just tested this solution[1] and it works as expected, if I understood your needs:

```
socat -u tcp4-listen:1934 - | tee >(socat - tcp4:127.0.0.1:1935) >(socat - tcp4:127.0.0.1:1936) > /dev/null
```

There must be processes already listening on 1935 and 1936 already before launching this otherwise the `socat` on the right will complain.

This is still a very brittle solution. I would advise trying alternative routes, like a temporary caching file or a pipe maybe.

[1] like that:

- `nc -l 127.0.0.1 1935` in a shell
- `nc -l 127.0.0.1 1936` in another shell
- the command above in the third shell
- and then in a fourth one: `echo "foobar" | nc 127.0.0.1 1934`
- and I do see "foobar" in output in first and second shell.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm accepting this as it does answer my original question. But as you said, this whole thing feels brittle, and I think I need to come at this problem from a whole other angle.

Answer (score 0):

Can you initiate socat in your destination(s)?

Just used `socat -d -d -b67108864 -U TCP4-LISTEN:65431,tcpwrap,tcpwrap-etc=.,reuseaddr,fork OPEN:filename`

with hosts.allow in current dir having a line:
`socat: address address address address`

-U reverses the direction so the server listens.

`socat TCP:server:65431 - |`..........  at the destination(s).